# htlatex in silent mode

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

It's possible to run `htlatex in silencemode` like `pdflatex`.

**pdflatex --draftmode --interaction=nonstopmode foo.tex > tmp.txt**

I have found only `nonstopmode/batchmode in htlatex`.

**htlatex source.tex "3" "" "" "--interaction==nonstopmode"**. Any ideas?

Comment: `htlatex ... > /dev/null` on a Unix system.

Comment: I have used `htlatex ... > c:\test.html` on a Windows system and it's working fine. Could you answer my question so that i will accept your answer for future viewers..

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no expert of Windows. According to [this (old) answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/923955) by Jon Skeet, you can use `> NUL` on Windows system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output redirection is obtained by adding `> <file>` to the command line.

So

```
htlatex "other options..." "--interaction=nonstopmode" > filename
```

will record the session in `filename`. This works on Unix shells and also with the Windows command line interface.

If no record is needed, use

```
> /dev/null
```

instead of `> filename` on Unix systems and

```
> NUL
```

on Windows (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313111/dev-null-in-windows). Note that `filename` is an arbitrary file name possibly including a path, but of course the user should be able to write in the pointed at directory.

Depending on the system setup, `> filename` might refuse to execute, if the file already exists. With a Bash shell, use `>| filename` for overriding the `noclobber` option; other command shell may have different workarounds.